# How to use mapbox.js default style in mapboxGL.js

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

before i used mapbox.js now i need use mapsboxGL.js but the mapbox.js style corresponds better to my app..

Mapbox.js
[image: mapbox.js]

VS

MapboxGL.js
[image: mapboxGL.js]

you know how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a Mapbox.js style in Mapbox GL JS.

Mapbox GL JS and Mapbox.js use very different rendering technologies and therefore have incompatible [style](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/) [specifications](http://mapnik.org/mapnik-reference/).

Have you considered using [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/) to tweak the GL style you are using?

Comment: Hello Lucas ! Thanks for your answer ! There a way to copy the style of Mapbox.js in Mapbox Studio and export to MapboxGL ?

Comment: No, you cannot use a Mapbox.js style in GL. You will have to start with the GL style and tweak it to fit your app's styling.

Comment: Ok Thanks Lucas ! :)

Comment: Hi ! I try to use custom html marker like mapbox js and is not working... there is any solution to create html marker ? Thanks